# Error message when unwrapping while using the subdivision modifier

Tags: uv, subdivision-surface

I know this question was asked before and despite searching the whole day the internet I didn't found an answer that solved my problem. I'm a realtive new user of Blender (2.93) but not new in working with 3D programs.

When I unwrap an object and want to use the Subdivision Surface Modifier I get the following message: "Subdivision Surface Modifier needs to be first to work with unwrap".
This message is totaly clear but I always get this massage no matter the objects I've created. The Subdivision Surface Modifier is always the one and only Modifier I use in this case, so it's always first! No other modifiers where used before, applied or deleted later, no changes where made later on. I also get this error while trying to unwrap a just created simply object such as a uvsphere with added Subdivision Surface Modifier.

I've read the SSM should be usable with uvunwrap otherwise the option "Use Subdivision Surface" also wouldn't exist, I think.
Is there any option I have to turn on/off? Do I oversea something? A special kind of work order?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share some blend file with that error? I would like to see it because I have never seen that kind of error before

Comment: Ok, I uploaded the file here: [link](https://pasteall.org/blend/1db41653066e46eb8f10ffeebd2d1aa3)

Comment: Hope this works. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing, no errors, I am not sure if I am doing the same steps as you are doing, subdivision works and can be added or applied as well... but when I have active subdivision and try to hit U -> unwrap, it simply unwraps, no errors. Did I miss something? Are you using some addons or a clean default build?

Comment: Ok, than something seems to be wrong with my installation or system I think.
The only AddOns I use are the "LoopTools" and I tried lately "CrowdRender" but this AddOn is turned off because I don't need it now. My workflow ist simply. I add a UVSpere, add the Subdivision Modifier, set Shade Smooth, turn on Edit Mode to mark the seams and run the Unwrap. When I try to activate "Use Subdivision Surface" the error appears. It works only when the Modifier is applied. But this is useless.
Is there a kind of reset for Blender I could try? Or maybe I should reinstall it ...

Comment: When you go to **Edit -> Preferences** down at the left side there is a button with 3 lines, there is an option to restart blender to default settings. If it doesn't help, try to install different version or reinstall, if it won't help then it must be something related to your system if I cannot replicate it in your file